# CSS hover effect that changes background color

Tags: php, css

I was hoping to find out how [zazzle.com](http://zazzle.com) does their hover effect.  I want to make an effect like that using pure CSS.  I don't need the dropdown just the whole background of my element to change color.

### CSS

```
/* the styles for the HTML elements */
html {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#f3f3f3 0%,transparent 15%, transparent 90%,#000000 100% ),
              url("../Images/bg.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
   height:135%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
footer{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(119, 75, 77);
}
footer p {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    margin: 0;
}
#headerLeft{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
#headerRight{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    text-align: right;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0


}
li{
    display: inline;

}
nav li:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;

}



.floatRight{

}
nav li{
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    display: inline;
}

textarea {
    width: 25em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .15em 0;
}
br {
    clear: both;
}

/* the styles for the div tags that divide the page into sections */



#content {
    float: left;
    width: 580px;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#left_column {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: .5em;
}
#right_column {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: .6;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: .5em 2em;
}
/********************************************************************
* styles for the classes
********************************************************************/
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
}
.cart_qty  {
    text-align: right;
    width: 3em;
}
.button_form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.inline {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: .5em;
}
/********************************************************************
* Styles for the Product Manager application
********************************************************************/
#category_table form {
    margin: 0;
}
#category_table td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .15em .5em 0 0;
}
#add_category_form {
    margin: 0;
}
#add_category_form input {
    margin-right: .5em;  
}
#add_admin_user_form  label {
    width: 8.5em;
}
#edit_and_delete_buttons {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#edit_and_delete_buttons form {
    display: inline;
}
#image_manager input {
    margin: .25em;
}
/********************************************************************
* Styles for the Product Catalog application
********************************************************************/
#product_image_column {
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
}
/*******************************************************************/
#add_to_cart_form {
    margin: .25em;
}
#add_to_cart_form input {
    float: none;
}
/*******************************************************************/
#cart {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em .25em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#cart_header th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#cart_footer td {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    font-style: bold;
}
#cart td {
    padding: .25em 0;
}
/*******************************************************************/
#login_form label {
    width: 5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
#login_form input[text] {

}
#payment_form label {
    width: 8em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
#payment_form input[text] {
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
#add_category label {
    text-align: left;
    width: 3em;
}
#add_category input { 
    margin-right: .25em;
}
```

### PHP PAGE

```
<?php
    require_once('model/database.php');
    require_once('model/category_db.php');
?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!-- the head section -->
    <head>
        <title>Willie's Fishing Supply</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="<?php echo $app_path ?>main.css" />
    </head>

    <!-- the body section -->
    <body>
        <header>

          <ul>
              <section id="headerLeft">
                  <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $app_path; ?>">
                            <h1>Willie's Fishing Supply</h1>
                        </a>
                    </li> 

              </section>
              <section id="headerRight">

                    <?php
                    // Check if user is logged in and
                    // display appropriate account links
                    $account_url = $app_path . 'account';
                    $logout_url = $account_url . '?action=logout';
                    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) :
                    ?>

                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $account_url; ?>">My Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $logout_url; ?>">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $account_url; ?>">Login/Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $app_path . 'cart'; ?>">Cart</a>
                    </li>
              </section>
                </ul>  
        </header>
        <nav> 
            <ul><?php
            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach($categories as $category) :
                $name = $category['categoryName'];
                $id = $category['categoryID'];
                $url = $app_path . 'catalog?category_id=' . $id;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
               <?php echo $name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


            </ul>
        </nav>


        <section id = "wrapper">
```

Comment: but, what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.aj_R-departmentLinks > li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Or You can simply do `background-color:` instead of writing out all that every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change background color on an element use the :hover selector

`.element {
          background-color: blue;
     }
     .element:hover {
          background-color: red;
     }`